# Cleaning current directory rm -r * on unix

Tags: linux, shell

This is a correct way to clean current directory right?

```
rm -r * .
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I normally just move one level up in the hierarchy, then remove the directory by name and recreate it:

```
cd ..
rm -rf dirname
mkdir dirname
cd dirname
```

because that eliminates the error case of using `rm -rf *` in the wrong directory.

**Note:** If the directory has non-standard permissions or is owned by some other account, then you'll lose that when you delete and re-create the directory. That's not something that comes up very often for me, but it's worth thinking about.

If I needed to do this in a script, I'd probably make a function that saves the current directory, moves up a level, deletes and creates the new empty dir, and moves there.

Comment: +1 It also eliminates the possibility of overflowing the command-line args. IIRC, you can only have 1k bytes for cmd args, so `rm *` may expand to more than that. Recreating the dir IMHO is the best option (unless you have hardlinks, but that's just dirty).

Comment: I'm not sure this approach guarantees that dirname is created with the same permissions/ownership it had before you deleted it, might be a good idea to check for that before deleting.

Comment: @AnonymousLurker, I did mention the permissions issue. This is the 90% solution for me - I rarely have directories with odd permissions (at least compared to the number of directories with weirdly-named files).

Comment: @MarkBessey I suggest you put a more visible word of caution (regarding permissions on the directory) into your answer.

Answer (score 6):

No, and for several reasons: 1) that command will try to remove `.`, which is the current directory, and will thus fail; 2) that command will not remove "hidden" files that begin with a '.' character; 3) the command will not remove directories.

You could use `rm -rf *`.  This will remove all files and directories, but it will not remove the dotfiles. You could use `find . -type f | xargs rm` to remove all files including hidden ones, but this won't remove directories.

So, you can use this:

```
$ find . -print0 -type f -o -type d -not -name '\.' | xargs -0 rm -rf
```

Here you recursively find all files and directories (as long as they are not called '.') and then remove them. The `-print0` and `-0` arguments allow it to correctly handle filenames with whitespace in their names.

Comment: This code won't delete all items. Just think of an item with a space in its name. So better use `-print0` with `find` and `-0` with `xargs`.

Comment: Is Unix much different from Linux? I can use `rm --recursive * .*[^.]*` on Linux, and was wondering if this would work on Unix.

Comment: @PaddyLandau That's not a comment to this answer, really; it's a separate question. And "Unix" is a very broad term, encompassing everything from HP-UX and AIX to Mac OS X. That said, it looks to me like that `rm` command would remove all non-dot-files, and all dot-files which contain at least one non-dot character. Try `touch ...` (yes, three periods), then running it.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling — thanks, but I was offering this as an alternative. I wasn't sure if it would work on Unix (I use Linux), which is why I posted a comment instead of a separate answer. If it works on Linux, I'd consider it a simple answer. BTW, `touch ...` does indeed create a hidden file called `...` in Linux.

Comment: @PaddyLandau ...which your `rm` command doesn't delete (I just tried it).

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thank you. It seems that my `rm` statement needs tweaking to include files of that format. If I manage to figure it out, I'll post back here.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this, if the -mindepth and -delete switches are available:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -delete
```

If you want to stick with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/find.html), you can do this (as seen on [unix.com](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/23528-remove-contents-directory-but-not-directory-2.html)):

```
find . \( ! -name . -prune \) -exec rm -rf {} \+
```

Answer (score 1):

One easy solution if you don't want to use find is to remove the current directory then recreate it:

```
rm -rf "`pwd`" && mkdir "`pwd`" && cd "`pwd`"
```

Comment: You'd probably want to cache `pwd`. I'm not sure if this would work properly after you delete it. `_dir=$(pwd) ; rm -rf "$_dir" && ...`. Haven't tested it though, so I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using bash (version 4 or above), you can use the `dotglob` shell option to include filenames beginning with a dot in your glob.

```
shopt -s dotglob
rm -r -- *
```

The above will break on directories containing many hundreds of thousands of files; in that case, you could use `printf` (which, being a bash builtin, [laughs in the face of ARG_MAX](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/argmax/)) and `xargs` (which will supply a safe number of arguments to `rm`).

```
shopt -s dotglob
printf '%q ' * | xargs rm -r --
```

You can unset `dotglob` once you are done with:

```
shopt -u dotglob
```

---

Another way of doing it without messing around with shell options would be:

```
rm -r -- * .[^.]* ..?*
##  or
printf '%q ' * .[^.]* ..?* | xargs rm -r --
```

The first glob `*` will match everything in the current directory that doesn't begin with a dot; the second one `.[^.]*` matches everything that begins with a dot, followed by a single non-dot character, followed by any number of other characters; the third glob matches two dots, followed by any one character, followed by any number of other characters. This could be useful if you're stuck in a shell without a dotglob option; however, in such a case `printf` may not be a shell builtin, or may lack the `%q` flag (which quotes all the spaces and unusual characters in the arguments fed to it, making them safe to pass to `xargs`), so you should probably use one of the `find`-based solutions in such a case.

Comment: If you have a huge directory listing, this could fail because of the number of CMD args.

Comment: @tjameson yes, though that would have to be a pretty huge number of files...

Comment: I ran into that just this past week at work. It was something around 500,000 files...

Comment: @tjameson ...well, OK then, I'll edit in a disclaimer